# Codeacademy code-CSS selectors 18/23

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So I'm going through HTML/CSS on Codeacademy and I just want to know why I can't put paragraph tags into this section of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>Result</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Add your HTML below!-->
        <div>
        <a href="http://Link">Google</a>
        <a href="http://Link">Google</a>
        <a href="Link">MSN</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

by where the `<a href>`s are. It messes up the CSS, here:

```
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;}

a:first-child{  
    color:#CDBE70;
}

a:nth-child(3){
    color:#ffc125;
}
```

Not sure if the code will show up correctly here so I will edit it accordingly.

Comment: where do you want to add the paragraph... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5j9DR/1/ can you edit the fiddle to create the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `first-child` and `nth-child` selectors are NOT related to the identifiers before them!  While you might think that `a:first-child` will affect your first `<a>` tag, it actually ONLY affects `<a>` tags that are ALSO the first child.  So, if you add a `<p>` before your links, all your CSS will be thrown off.

It sounds like you want `first-of-type` and `nth-of-type`.  These rules function like you would expect them to.

See the [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type)

**EDIT:**

Imagine the following list (which I'm assuming looks like what you were trying to do; please clarify if not.)

```
<div>
  <p>Hello!</p>
  <a>Link1</a>
  <a>Link2</a>
  <a>Link3</a>
</div>
```

In this case, an `a:first-child` rule won't match *anything*, because there are no `<a>` tags that are also `first-child`.  There is a `<p>` tag that's a first-child, and there are `<a>` tags that are 2nd, 3rd, and 4th children, but there is no `a:first-child`.

Comment: But... isn't the first <a> tag a first child or am I confusing something here? Codeacademy says the code there is correct though, in the CSS. So why is it though that adding a <p> tag messes everything up? Still sort of confused.

Comment: So if I change the a: to a p:first-child{} code then it would work in theory? Because I just tried it and it's not like that apparently, so I feel like I'm missing something. I feel like this is a little insignificant to talk about but I'm just curious why it wouldn't work in this way. However yes that code is what I was trying to do, along with adding <p> tags to the rest of the links so they look nicer instead of all clumped at the top.

Comment: In theory, that should be working in any modern browser... if you know how to use the Chrome inspector, try adding custom rules to this SO page for `p:first-child` and `p:first-child-of-type` to see how they select different items.  Also, if you are wrapping all your `<a>` tags with `<p>`, don't forget that this makes all your `<a>` tags first-children of the `<p>` tags!